# Query for Finding Hyphen in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the records in the database like this which are as follows. I want to search in the Account Column which is my last column in my AccountDetails Table. I want to searching based on conditions like

1- want to findt hose records which contain a hyphen after 1st number (which can be anything)
12- want to find those records which contain a hyphen after 2nd number (which can be anything)
123-want to find those records which contain a hyphen after 3rd number (which can be anything)

**AccountDetail Table**

```
230263  jba 100-1807
230263  jba 100-1808
230263  jba 100-1809
235572  jba 99-1818
235572  jba 99-1819
235572  jba 99-1820
235572  jba 9-1818
235572  jba 9-1819
235572  jba 9-1820
```

I have done like this

```
Select * From WF_Account Where CompanyId = 'jba' and Account Like '%-%'
```

Comment: Just separate 3rd column and calculate first number's digits :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure which version of sql you are running.

but in SQL Server you can use `CHARINDEX` or in sql 2012 `FINDSTRING`

e.g

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('-', Col1) > 0
```

EDIT:

You can also use `PATINDEX` which returns the position of string for a pattern.

so maybe:

```
WHERE PATINDEX('%-', Col1) <= 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query:

*1- want to find those records which contain a hyphen after 1st number (which can be anything)*

```
SELECT *
FROM WF_Account
WHERE CompanyId = 'jba'
AND CHARINDEX('-', Account) = 2
```

*12- want to find those records which contain a hyphen after 2nd number (which can be anything)*

```
SELECT *
FROM WF_Account
WHERE CompanyId = 'jba'
AND CHARINDEX('-', Account) = 3
```

*123-want to find those records which contain a hyphen after 3rd number (which can be anything)*

```
SELECT *
FROM WF_Account
WHERE CompanyId = 'jba'
AND CHARINDEX('-', Account) = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this using [Regular expression](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-asarc/srg1100e/sqlref/@Generic__BookTextView/73386;pt=73946).

1- want to findt hose records which contain a hyphen after 1st number (which can be anything)

```
Select * From WF_Account Where CompanyId = 'jba' and Account Like '_-%';
```

12- want to find those records which contain a hyphen after 2nd number (which can be anything)

```
Select * From WF_Account Where CompanyId = 'jba' and Account Like '__-%';
```

123-want to find those records which contain a hyphen after 3rd number (which can be anything)

```
Select * From WF_Account Where CompanyId = 'jba' and Account Like '___-%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LIKE's [] character set option. See also the ESCAPE clause if you need to put a hyphen into a character set.

```
select * from WF_Account
-- Hypen after one digit
where Account like '[0-9]-%'
-- Hypen after two digits
or Account  like '[0-9][0-9]-%'
-- Hypen after three digits
or Account  like '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-%'
```